# Boost Unit Test framework can't find main function

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I have this minimal unit test:

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE a_test

struct Color{};

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(color_test)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(std::is_pod<Color>());
}
```

However when I compile it like so

```
clang -std=c++14 -lc++ -lboost_unit_test_framework a_test.cc -o main
```

I get an undefined symbol for _main. `-lboost_unit_test_framework` uses the shared library.

I used this library before, and I remember not having to declare a main function myself, as it was automatically running the several `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE`s I define.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `BOOST_TEST_MODULE` define goes before the include. Boost detects it and then generates a main function for you.

Comment: @melak47 Unfortunately that doesn't work either

Comment: Ah, you're also missing `libboost_test_exec_monitor.a`! :)

Comment: Also, hang on - if you want to use the shared library, I believe you have to `#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK`. Without that it assumes the static library.

Comment: That's it! I don't understand how the program can decide whether to use the static library or the shared library, isn't that the job of the linker? Anyway, if you post that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When linking Boost.Test dynamically, you need to define `BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK` ([see boost docs here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/link_references/link_boost_test_dyn_link.html)).

You may also have to link `boost_test_exec_monitor`.

Also, all the configuration macros need to be defined before including the library header to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

@melak47 is also right. I believe the following should work, too:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE my_tests TestSuites // to define main()
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

struct Color{};

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(MyColorTests)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(color_test)
{
    BOOST_CHECK( std::is_pod<Color>() );
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

If you link multiple such modules together, make sure that `BOOST_TEST_MODULE` is only defined in one of them, *before* the include.

Comment: Since there's the master test suite, I don't think it's strictly necessary to have another top-level suite. See this [minimal example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/intro.html#boost_test.intro.starter_example). Can't hurt though :)